# In c program, why free memory of string (which copy from strcpy) in osx is not woking?

Tags: c, macos, memory

my osx version is 10.12,

when I copy string from origin string , then free it, it's not working,

But in linux(centos 6.2) is ok, I print copy is invalid.

I don't find the reason, It's really confused me.

here is code:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 char *copy;
 char *origin = "tutorialspoint";
 copy = (char *) malloc(15);
 strcpy(copy, origin);

 free(copy); //not working
 printf("string = %s,  Address = %u\n", copy, copy);
 printf("origin = %s,  Address = %u\n", origin, origin);
 return(0);
}
```

most strange thing is when I free memory for `origin`, copy's memory also be freed

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 char *copy;
 char *origin = "tutorialspoint";
 copy = (char *) malloc(15);
 strcpy(copy, origin);

 free(origin); //working for copy too 
 printf("string = %s,  Address = %u\n", copy, copy);
 printf("origin = %s,  Address = %u\n", origin, origin);
 return(0);
}
```

Comment: There's an awful lot of undefined behavior going on in this program.

Comment: The code is horribly wrong, but it's not really a duplicate. The answer needs to go further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is your placement of `free(copy)`, move it **after** you make use of `copy`, otherwise you are attempting to read from a variable that has already been `freed` (an uninitialized value - invoking **Undefined Behavior**), (as @Pras correctly notes you `free (copy)`, not `free (origin)`, e.g.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    char *copy;
    char *origin = "tutorialspoint";
    copy = malloc (strlen (origin) + 1);
    strcpy(copy, origin);

    printf("string = %s,  Address = %p\n", copy, (void *)copy);
    printf("origin = %s,  Address = %p\n", origin, (void *)origin);
    free(copy);  /* works find here */
    return(0);
}
```

**note:** use of `%p` for the pointer address.

You should also **validate ALL memory allocations**, e.g.

```
    if (!(copy = malloc (strlen (origin) + 1))) {
        fprintf (stderr, "error: virtual memory exhausted.\n");
        return 1;
    }
```

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/origin
string = tutorialspoint,  Address = 0xbe3010
origin = tutorialspoint,  Address = 0x400710
```

---

**copy is freed**

Continuing from your comment, `copy` is in fact freed. How can you tell? You run you code through a memory/error checking program like `valgrind`, e.g.

```
$ valgrind ./bin/origin
==10564== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==10564== Copyright (C) 2002-2015, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==10564== Using Valgrind-3.11.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==10564== Command: ./bin/origin
==10564==
string = tutorialspoint,  Address = 0x51d8040
origin = tutorialspoint,  Address = 0x400710
==10564==
==10564== HEAP SUMMARY:
==10564==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==10564==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 15 bytes allocated
==10564==
==10564== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==10564==
==10564== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==10564== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

As you can see, all memory allocated had in fact been freed and -- no leaks are possible and there were 0 errors from 0 contexts.

Comment: but `copy ` still not freed in osx

Comment: No, not yet, you call `free` after `printf("string = %s,  Address = %p\n", copy, (void *)copy);` or you invoke **Undefined Behavior** in your code by violating the rule against attempting to read from a variable that has been freed. Anything can happen, SegFault, Strange values, Normal Values -- its **Undefined**. (You can set copy to `NULL` and re-allocate, but between the `free` and any subsequent `reallocation` you cannot read from `copy`.)

Comment: It's perfectly normal that the data appears to be valid after calling `free` - `free` just tells to the allocator that it can reuse that block, why should it bother overwriting the old data? It'll be overwritten by whoever will get that memory block next time someone - for example - does a similarly sized `malloc`.

Comment: Yes, but that is still **UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR**. The facts that the memory released by `free` has not yet been reassigned, or otherwise used, does not change that fact. You can access value within a allocated block of memory **so long as that block of memory remains valid**, you are noway in control of what happens after `free`. It's just the rule...

Comment: @DavidCRankin of course, I'm just explaining to OP what he is seeing, since the fact that the memory is still accessible is what seems to be bugging him most.

Comment: Gotcha, that what we are all hoping the takeaway will be.

Answer (score 1):

In you program origin is not allocated on heap, so freeing it can result in undefined behavior

Answer (score 0):

Do you wonder what should happen when your computer behaves in an... *undefined*... manner? Should it:

- a/ emit an error message,
- b/ crash,
- c/ read your mind and function as you intended, or
- d/ behave in an *undefined* manner?

Hint: the first three options seem very much *defined*, don't they?

**Your code invokes undefined behaviour.** Namely, these two lines in your first example:

```
printf("string = %s,  Address = %u\n", copy, copy);
printf("origin = %s,  Address = %u\n", origin, origin);
```

... and this line, in your second example:

```
free(origin);
```

- You should be using `%p` to print a `void *` ([as David pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43861633/1989425)). Using `%u` to print anything but an `unsigned int` is a lie to `printf`, which causes undefined behaviour.
- You shouldn't *use* (i.e. attempt to print the string it *used to* point to) `copy` after you've `free`d it; that's also undefined behaviour.
- You shouldn't `free` anything that wasn't returned by `malloc`, `calloc` or `realloc`; again, undefined behaviour.

Note that undefined behaviour may appear to work *coincidentally*, hence the string that the `free`d object once contained *may still appear to exist*; as programmers we don't like relying upon coincidence, but it just so happens that the *undefined* nature of the behaviour might correspond to your code *working coincidentally*. It might also coincidentally (or not) *fail subtly* or *catastrophically* in other situations. Hence, we should *avoid* undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Running the first example will in many cases still print out the `tutorialspoint` string for both `copy` and `origin`. `free()` does not modify the memory in the location you malloc'ed and it also does not change the address of the pointer to origin, so in theory you can still see still see the value by printing out `copy`. But, you should NOT depend on this. After running `free()` you should consider the pointer unusable until reassigned as another process may overwrite that memory space.

The second example prints for similar reasons, but `origin` is a heap pointer and can not be free'd. ONLY malloc'ed pointers can be safely free'd using `free()`

Comment: As I wrote in a previous comment, "... you're attempting to *define* the *undefined behaviour*, which is... not a good idea *unless* you're talking about a specific implementation in which case you're not talking about C, but a subset of C which behaves in a subtly stricter and non-portable manner."

Comment: @Seb yes, i've fixed the typo to refer `copy`. I think I noted that it is not-reliable/portable, but the original question was also specific to a specific os and that's the scenario I described as well. Although it is undefined by the specification of `free`, it is very reproducible and predictable on a single os, so describing that it is just `undefined` fails to explain why it may appear to an amateur that it doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: Is it *very reproducible and predictable on a single os* for *every piece of hardware, compiler and standard library version produced for that OS*, and for *every permutation of compiler flags and optimisations available*? That's **a lot** of testing, and a **bold** statement to make; I doubt the truth of your statement. For example, I reckon [LLVM/Clang](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AddressSanitizer.html) and [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Instrumentation-Options.html) might prove you wrong if you use their address sanitizers (the links are to the documentation for that feature).

Comment: Upvoted because actually explains to OP what he is seeing, which is the whole point of his question. We can talk all day about how this is UB and must not be relied upon, but the original question asks for an explanation of a particular behavior that OP is seeing, which by the way is quite typical of many heap managers.

Comment: That being said: "After running free() you should consider the pointer unusable until reassigned as another process may overwrite that memory space." this is wrong on any "regular" operating system. Processes don't generally share the heap, so `free`d memory doesn't get reused cross-process (well, unless the heap manager gives it back to the OS, but in that case it's no longer accessible to your process and accessing its address gives a segfault). When a given user-mode memory block is reused is in the context of the same process (although possibly cross-thread).